# Laravel sentinel permission hasAccess

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, sentinel

I have user that has permission for "marketplace.category." but when I check using sentinel

```
$user->hasAnyAccess("marketplace.")
```

I got return false

Can somebody give me explanation about this?

thanks

Comment: Please check  your permission name should be `marketplace.category.` but you put `marketplace.`

Comment: **Note** You can use `Sentinel::hasAccess()` or `Sentinel::hasAnyAccess()` directly which will call the methods on the currently logged in user, incase there’s no user logged in, a `BadMethodCallException` will be thrown.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd but my current permission "marketplace.category." has parent for "marketplace.", can I just use it?

Comment: just for testing please put `marketplace.category.` instead of `marketplace.` please check its working or not

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd its working with "marketplace.category."

Comment: Are you set `marketplace.` permission with login user?